# getElementById throwing an error when trying to append while looping through a HTMLcollection

Tags: javascript

I was trying to append some dynamically created html. It throws an error while using getElementById. .audit-table-element is a div in DOM with that particular class.

```
<div class="audit-table-element"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('audit-table-element');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].getElementById("always-audit-table" + category.id + "")
            .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
            .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", auditTableRow);
}
```

**Error** - `TypeError: elems[i].getElementById is not a function`

When I remove the line getElementById("always-audit-table" + category.id + ""), appending is working, but gets appended at the wrong place. So i need to have that line for the HTML to be appended at the right place

Comment: `getElementbyId` works with document not with element.

Comment: @Shiladitya any workaround possible ? I have to use the id to get the correct element ! But, getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0] is working properly

Comment: Is `category.id` fixed for the entire loop? That would seem to imply multiple elements in the document share the same id, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: I cannot tell if there are many mistakes in the code, or what, but the div provided has a class name which does not match any in the javascript, and as Ry pointed out, it seems as though you may have invalid HTML if you have multiple elements with the same Id.

Comment: `audit-table-element` is a `class` or `ID` ?

Comment: can we have a code where you are creating dynamic element

Comment: `elems[i].getElementById("always-audit-table" + category.id + "")` this will not work because `elems[i]` is already an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`. Your code should be like below.

```
elems[i].querySelector("[id = always-audit-table" + category.id + "]")
        .getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
        .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", auditTableRow);
```

> **querySelector :** These are used to select HTML elements based on their id, classes, types, attributes, values of attributes, etc.

[Click here to learn more about querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your code looks like, but i try to create one example here. have a look to this, your doubts will be cleared out

```js
var testRow = "<tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>";

var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){ debugger;
  ele[i].querySelector("[id = id"+i+"]").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", testRow);
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
<div id='id0'>
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
<div class='test'>
<div id='id1'>
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
```